# Java Implementing math log function properly?

Tags: java, math, logging

so i have just this Math.log function in Java at this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_log.htm

On its example :

```
  Math.log(60984.1) = 11.018368453441132
```

I tried it on a calculator (i was actually just using windows scientific calculator) and typed in 60984.1 then log, which shows that it is equivalent to log(60984.1). But then the result was

```
  4.785216618906530669507
```

instead of the the 11.018368 of math.log function in java. What causes this inconsistency?
I am not really good at math an i am trying to implement an algorithm which uses a log sig function and a simple log. I don't even know how to do a simple log. The equation i am basing upon has no base. Just simple log. 
What is the right equivalent of log in Java?
Thank you :)

Comment: you are confusing `ln` and `log` which is logarithm10

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is an implied base in each of those methods.  The natural log (base `e`) is the result `11.018368453441132`, but the common log (base `10`) yields the result `4.785216618906530669507`.

The `Math` class supports both bases:

- [`Math.log`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log%28double%29) - base `e`
- [`Math.log10`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10%28double%29) - base `10`.

Windows Calculator's button "ln" supports the natural log ("ln" is the mathematical function name for the natural log), and it supports the button "log" for the common log.

Comment: Thank you for answering my last 2 questions clearly and precisely.

Answer (score 2):

Math.log uses log base `e`, which is the natural log. Windows calc maps `Log` to log base 10.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you want base 10 logarithm

```
 Math.log10
```